# constructors and destructors - c++

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor

I need to write a program that prints 100 stars on the screen (at random places), and then the stars disappear slowly - one after another. I'm not allowed to use loops nor recursions.
I've tried to play with the constructors and the destructors but I can't get the stars to disappear one after another (and not all together).
Any ideas?

Thanks,
Li

Sorry - forgot to mention i'm using c++

My current access violating useless code:

```
class star {
    int x;
    int y;
public:
    star(){
        x = rand()%80;
        y = rand()%80;
        PaintcharOnRandomLocation('*',x,y);
    };
    ~star(){
        PaintcharOnRandomLocation(' ',x,y);
    };

};

class printAll{
    star* arr;
public:
    printAll(){
    arr = new star[100];
    };


    ~printAll(){
        delete[] arr;
    };


};
void doNothing(printAll L){
};

void main()
{
    srand ( time(NULL) );   
    doNothing(printAll());

     getch();
};
```

Comment: What language?  Can you post your code?

Comment: What language or format are you writing this in?

Comment: What language are you using and what have you tried?  Sounds like homework...

Comment: Constructors and destructors are cool, try also to use finalizers :)

Comment: Why can't you use loops or recursion?  homework?

Comment: not homework - it's a question from a job interview :)

Comment: Can you write code with loops that writes code that doesn't have loops? That might solve the problem of no loops. Instead of `for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) { \* CODE *\ }`, you would just print the code 100 times.

Comment: What do you have so far?  Let's see some of your code.

Comment: The first question they asked me was easier - they simply wanted me to print 100 stars at random places without using any loops/recursions.
This is easy using a star class with an empty constructor that prints the star at a random place. Then, in main I created an array of 100 stars and then got the desired result.

Comment: I will post my code after this one more try (copy ctor?)

Comment: I just need to figure out how to post the code :) 2 minutes

Comment: Use goto or you could use Boost preprocessing library to paste it in.

Comment: The issue with your new code is all to do with your DoNothing function which forces a copy of your printall class. You don't really need this function at all - in main() try replacing 
DoNothing(PrintAll()); with 
PrintAll MyPrintAll();

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Seems the only way possible without loops/recursion is something like this:

```
class Star
{
  Star() 
  { 
     //constructor shows star in a a random place
  }
  ~Star()
  {
    //destructor removes star and sleeps for a random amount of time
  }
};

int main() 
{
   Star S[100];
}
```

This is really just a dumb trick because the compiler has to run the constructor for each star to initialise the array and then the destructor for EACH star as it goes out of scope.

It is also a bad trick as all the workings that go in the main function are opaque and invisible. It would obviously be better to use a loop in this context and putting the delay inside a destructor like this is really confusing and unmaintainable.

Comment: The trouble is, that in your code, the destructor won't get called at all, because S is just a pointer that does nothing when it goes out of scope.

Comment: @fat-lobyte:  `S` is not a pointer.  `S` is an array of 100 `Star` objects.

Answer (score 8):

This is not a runtime recursion:

```
template<int N>
struct Star
{
   Star() { DrawAtRandomPlace(); }
   ~Star() { RemoveSlowly(); }
   Star<N-1> star;
};

template<> struct Star<0> {};

int main()
{
  Star<100> stars;
}
```

The code above will generate 100 different instantiations of the Star template. RAII will guarantee the order of drawing and removing.

Comment: These are not the droids you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your final comment, can you have the destructor of your `star` class do a delay? See for example the `sleep` or `usleep` functions.

Answer (score 0):

Since Destructors/Constructors are only an Idea, they're probably not the right title for your question.
I don't know what system/environment you are in, but how about this:

Create a buffer that contains a string with your stars, simply manually by typing them in the code.

Next, write a function that displays the buffer to whatever output window you use.

Then, you would need a function that has a static(!) pointer to the back of the buffer, and that does the following:

- Call the buffer printing function
- Write a null byte under the current pointer position
- Decrement the static pointer
- Wait for a period of time
- Raise a custom signal with [raise()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/csignal/)

In the main() function, you set the the Signal Handler for your custom signal to the function described above, and then you raise the custom signal.